# Adicionar um menu inferior

Tags: java, swing

Gostaria de fazer um menu inferior na minha aplicação java, para colocar hora e tempo de execução ou até alguma parte de configuração mesmo.
já tenho um `JMenuBar` na parte superior.

esse é meu código.

```
package tela;

import componente.MeuJDesktopPane;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;

public class TelaSistema extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static final MeuJDesktopPane jdp = new MeuJDesktopPane();
    private JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu jmCadastros = new JMenu("Cadastros");
    private JMenu cadRegiao = new JMenu("Região");
    private JMenu cadProduto = new JMenu("Produtos");
    private JMenu cadAlunoF = new JMenu("Aluno/Fornecedor");
    private JMenu cadExercicio = new JMenu("Exercícios");
    private JMenu jmMovimentacoes = new JMenu("Movimentações");
    private JMenu jmRelatorios = new JMenu("Relatórios");
    private JMenuItem jmiPais = new JMenuItem("País");
    private JMenuItem jmiEstado = new JMenuItem("Estado");
    private JMenuItem jmiCidade = new JMenuItem("Cidade");
    private JMenuItem jmiAluno = new JMenuItem("Aluno");
    private JMenuItem jmiMatricula = new JMenuItem("Matricula");
    private JMenuItem jmiMatriculaModalidade = new JMenuItem("Matricula Modalidade");
    private JMenuItem jmiGrupoMatricula = new JMenuItem("Grupo Matricula");
    private JMenuItem jmiGrupoMuscular = new JMenuItem("Grupo Muscular");
    private JMenuItem jmiExercicios = new JMenuItem("Exercícios");
    private JMenuItem jmiModalidade = new JMenuItem("Modalidade");
    private JMenuItem jmiFormaDePagamento = new JMenuItem("Forma de Pagamento");
    private JMenuItem jmiFornecedor = new JMenuItem("Fornecedor");
    private JMenuItem jmiMarca = new JMenuItem("Marca");
    private JMenuItem jmiTipo = new JMenuItem("Tipo");
    private JMenuItem jmiModelo = new JMenuItem("Modelo");
    private JMenuItem jmiLote = new JMenuItem("Lote Produto");
    private JMenuItem jmiProduto = new JMenuItem("Produto");
    private JMenuItem jmiTreino = new JMenuItem("Treino");
    private JMenuItem jmiAvaliacaoFisica = new JMenuItem("Avaliação Física");
    private JMenuItem jmiItemTreino = new JMenuItem("ItemTreino");
    private JMenuItem jmiPedidoCompra = new JMenuItem("Pedido Compra");
    private JMenuItem jmiTurma = new JMenuItem("Turma");
    private JMenuItem jmiTurmaAlunos = new JMenuItem("Turma Alunos");
    private JMenuItem jmiCompra = new JMenuItem("Compra");
    private JMenuItem jmiVenda = new JMenuItem("Venda");
    private JMenuItem jmiContaPagar = new JMenuItem("Conta Pagar");
    private JMenuItem jmiContaReceber = new JMenuItem("Conta Receber");
    private JMenuItem jmiCaixa = new JMenuItem("Caixa");
    private JMenuItem jmiRelatorioCliente = new JMenuItem("Cliente");
    JPanel jmInf = new JPanel();
    private JPanel jpBotoes = new JPanel();

    public TelaSistema() {
        setTitle("FIRE FITNESS");
        getContentPane().add(jdp);
        setJMenuBar(jmb);
        jmb.add(jmCadastros);
        jmb.add(jmMovimentacoes);
        jmb.add(jmRelatorios);
      //  menuInferior();
        InsereLogo();
        InsereIcones();
        adicionaItensMenu();
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void menuInferior() {
         getContentPane().add("Soult", jpBotoes);
         jpBotoes.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    }

    public void adicionaItensMenu() {
        adicionaItemNoMenu(jmCadastros, cadRegiao);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(jmCadastros, cadProduto);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(jmCadastros, cadAlunoF);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(jmCadastros, cadExercicio);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadRegiao, jmiPais);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadRegiao, jmiEstado);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadRegiao, jmiCidade);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadAlunoF, jmiAluno);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadAlunoF, jmiMatricula);
        JSeparator sep = new JSeparator();
        jmiMatricula.add(sep);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadAlunoF, jmiGrupoMatricula);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadExercicio, jmiGrupoMuscular);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadAlunoF, jmiMatriculaModalidade);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadAlunoF, jmiTurmaAlunos);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadExercicio, jmiExercicios);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadExercicio, jmiModalidade);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(jmCadastros, jmiFormaDePagamento);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadAlunoF, jmiFornecedor);
//        JSeparator sep1 = new JSeparator();
//        cadProduto.add(sep1);        
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadProduto, jmiMarca);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadProduto, jmiTipo);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadProduto, jmiModelo);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadProduto, jmiLote);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadProduto, jmiProduto);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadExercicio, jmiTreino);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(jmCadastros, jmiPedidoCompra);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadAlunoF, jmiAvaliacaoFisica);
        //adicionaItemNoMenu(jmCadastros, jmiTreino);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(cadAlunoF, jmiTurma);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(jmMovimentacoes, jmiCompra);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(jmMovimentacoes, jmiVenda);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(jmMovimentacoes, jmiContaPagar);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(jmMovimentacoes, jmiContaReceber);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(jmMovimentacoes, jmiCaixa);
        adicionaItemNoMenu(jmRelatorios, jmiRelatorioCliente);
    }

    public void adicionaItemNoMenu(JMenu menu, JMenuItem menuItem) {
        menu.add(menuItem);
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == jmiPais) {
            TelaCadastroPais.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiEstado) {
            TelaCadastroEstado.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiCidade) {
            TelaCadastroCidade.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiAluno) {
            TelaCadastroAluno.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiMatricula) {
            TelaCadastroMatricula.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiGrupoMatricula) {
            TelaCadastroGrupoMatricula.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiGrupoMuscular) {
            TelaCadastroGrupoMuscular.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiExercicios) {
            TelaCadastroExercicios.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiModalidade) {
            TelaCadastroModalidade.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiMatriculaModalidade) {
            TelaCadastroMatriculaModalidade.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiFormaDePagamento) {
            TelaCadastroFormaPagamento.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiFornecedor) {
            TelaCadastroFornecedor.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiMarca) {
            TelaCadastroMarca.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiTipo) {
            TelaCadastroTipo.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiModelo) {
            TelaCadastroModelo.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiLote) {
            TelaCadastroLoteProduto.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiProduto) {
            TelaCadastroProduto.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiTreino) {
            TelaCadastroTreino.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiPedidoCompra) {
            TelaCadastroPedidoCompra.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiAvaliacaoFisica) {
            TelaCadastroAvaliacaoFisica.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiTurma) {
            TelaCadastroTurma.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiTurmaAlunos) {
            TelaCadastroTurmaAlunos.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiCompra) {
            TelaCadastroCompra.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiVenda) {
            //  TelaCadastroVenda.getTela();
        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiContaPagar) {
            TelaCadastroContaPagar.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiContaReceber) {
            //  TelaCadastroContaReceber.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiCaixa) {
            //TelaCadastroCaixa.getTela();

        } else if (ae.getSource() == jmiRelatorioCliente) {

        }
    }

    public void InsereIcones() {
        jmCadastros.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/cadastros.png")));
        jmMovimentacoes.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/movimentacao.png")));
        jmRelatorios.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/relatorio.png")));
        jmiFornecedor.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/fornecedor.png")));
        // jmiFuncionario.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/funcionario.png")));
        jmiProduto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/produto1.png")));
        jmiEstado.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/cidade.png")));
        cadRegiao.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/Regiao.png")));
        jmiEstado.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/cidade.png")));
        jmiCidade.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/cidade.png")));
        jmiPais.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/Regiao.png")));
        jmiExercicios.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/exercicio.png")));
        jmiCompra.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/compra1.png")));
        jmiMarca.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/marca.png")));
        //  jmiTipo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/tipo.png")));
    }

    public void InsereLogo() {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/imagens/FireFitness.png");
        Image iconeTitulo = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
        this.setIconImage(iconeTitulo);
    }

    public void centralizar(JInternalFrame janela) {
        Dimension d = janela.getDesktopPane().getSize();
        janela.setLocation((d.width - janela.getSize().width) / 2, (d.height - janela.getSize().height) / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: `import componente.MeuJDesktopPane;` - Coloque o código dessa classe na pergunta também.

Comment: Tem um monte de classes nesse código ai que impedem de executá-lo. Ou você remove as dependencias ou adiciona todas essas classes na pergunta.

Comment: Tem certeza que quer um menu, não é só uma barra de status que está precisando? Um JPanel bastaria para isso, como mostram as respostas.

Answer (score 2):

> para colocar hora e tempo de execução ou até alguma parte de configuração.

Para isso citado, apenas coloque um `JPanel` no `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, e dê a ele uma borda para separar visualmente do resto do conteúdo.

Ex:

```
public class FrmExemploStatusBar {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setSize(200, 200);

    // cria a barra inferior e insere no espaço inferior do JFrame
    JPanel statusPanel = new JPanel();
    statusPanel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
    frame.add(statusPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    statusPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), 16));
    statusPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(statusPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel("status");
    statusLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    statusPanel.add(statusLabel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Resultado do exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Utilizando JMenuBar**

```
public class FrmExemploStatusBar {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setSize(200, 200);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Teste");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Stack");
    menu.add(menuItem);
    frame.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 

    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não se adiciona JMenubar dessa forma ai, somente com `setJMenuBar()`. Não é a toa que existe um método só pra adicionar ela na tela.

Comment: Pode me explicar porque não? Dizer que é errado apenas por existir um método que facilita a inserção de forma padrão é um equívoco.

Comment: Você chegou a testar? O menu está embaixo, mas olha a forma como as opções abrem. Se for uma aplicação de tela inteira nem será possivel acessar algumas opções, pois a orientação dos itens ainda é vertical pra baixo da tela. Apesar de funcionar, não significa que seja correto de se fazer.

Comment: Está assim porque a dimensão do `JFrame` no código é 200x200, caso seja tela cheia o mesmo abre para cima. Só testar.

Comment: O correto seria o menu sempre seguir sua orientação de posicionamento, e não somente de acordo com o tamanho da tela. Ou seja, ele deveria abrir pra cima sempre, como ocorre ao adicionar no topo. Tem um outro pequeno detalhe, se adicionar o menu usando borderlayout, como vai exibir um painel de horas, como o OP disse? O borderlayout vai "inflar" o menu por toda a parte inferior.

Comment: O "correto" seria colocar o JMenu no topo. Isso se for o que a pergunta requer (não está clara), pois pelo que entendi, a primeira solução é o que a pergunta precisa (vamos esperar o autor). O que apresentei são ideias que possam ajudar e encaminhar a pergunta para ele não ter que desenvolver um componente do zero. Acho válido seus apontamentos quanto a comportamentos indesejáveis, mas não afirmações sem testar pelo menos o código.

Comment: Tudo que afirmei foi baseado em testes. Por que eu faria afirmações sem certeza? Não adianta dar uma resposta que responde a pergunta mas que vai gerar outros problemas. "Ensinar errado" não é o caminho. Se a pergunta não está clara, o recomendado é fazer como eu e o victor fizemos, solicitar melhores esclarecimentos. De qualquer forma, não vale a pena ficar batendo boca aqui, minha intenção foi alertar erros na resposta, mas você tem todo o direito de discordar, assim como eu tenho de votar negativamente por achar que não está boa.

Comment: Me referi a parte de dizer que o `JMenu` abriria para baixo mesmo em tela cheia. Concordo com você em tudo, e digo que essas discussões revigoram nosso raciocínio. Vamos esperar esclarecimentos